# CXF Client: How to ignore @WebServiceClient annotation

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I have a Third party jar that contains class SampleClass with `@javax.xml.ws.WebServiceClient` annotation. I have used CXF in my project for REST layer and not for Web Services. However, since CXF infrastructure is configured for my project, it is trying to auto-wire into SampleClass when I instantiate it (In fact it is ending up in an error when trying to do so). I want to use the class as a simple POJO and not web service client. is there a way I can tell CXF to ignore `@javax.xml.ws.WebServiceClient` annotation?

Just for information, the exception I get is:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.injection.ResourceInjector.invokePostConstruct(ResourceInjector.java:302)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.injection.ResourceInjector.construct(ResourceInjector.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.Jsr250BeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(Jsr250BeanPostProcessor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:463)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:404)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:375)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:263)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:170)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:260)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:184)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:430)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:729)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext.<init>(BusApplicationContext.java:88)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createApplicationContext(SpringBusFactory.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:94)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:87)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:65)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:54)
    at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:70)
    at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:107)
    at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:98)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:64)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.wsdl.WSDLExtensionRegister.createCompatExtensor(WSDLExtensionRegister.java:63)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.wsdl.WSDLExtensionRegister.registerYokoCompatibleExtensors(WSDLExtensionRegister.java:47)
    ... 34 more
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:81)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:141)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:133)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:65)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had used Super() in our class which extends from Service.
The code for the parent “Service” class is

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.xml.ws/jaxws-api/2.2.8/javax/xml/ws/Service.java#92

Which in turn calls the Static method “Provider.provider()” to load the
provider at the runtime.
Code for which is

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.xml.ws/jaxws-api/2.2.8/javax/xml/ws/spi/Provider.java#Provider.provider%28%29

Javadoc comment on this method is:

> Blockquote

Creates a new provider object.

The algorithm used to locate the provider subclass to use consists of the
following steps:

- If a resource with the name of META-INF/services/javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider
  exists, then its first line, if present, is used as the UTF-8 encoded name
  of the implementation class.
- If the $java.home/lib/jaxws.properties file exists and it is readable by
  the java.util.Properties.load(InputStream) method and it contains an entry
  whose key is javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider, then the value of that entry is used
  as the name of the implementation class.
- If a system property with the name javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider is defined,
  then its value is used as the name of the implementation class.
- Finally, a default implementation class name is used.

> Blockquote

CXF seems to have chosen first way to load its Provider implementation. i.e:
 "If a resource with the name of META-INF/services/javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider
exists, then its first line, if present, is used as the UTF-8 encoded name
of the implementation class."

CXF jar has this file inside the jar with Provider class mentioned as a CXF implementation. Since this is the first thing that is used for lookup, CXF's provider will be loaded instead of the default provider. However, our implementation expected default provider to be loaded.

The only viable work around that we could think of is to add the file javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider ourselves under META-INF\services and specify the provider as default implementation class com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl. The only risk with this is class com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl is an internal implementation of JRE and is not bound to API contract. So the class name/package can potentially change with future releases.